# C# Listen TCP Port

Tags: c#, tcp, tcplistener

I want to listen a TCP port.
The scenario:

SIP server, and client-program. The SIP server may use port 5010 to listen and establish multiple connections. The client connects from his pc to the server via port 5010.

When a packet is received on that port, an event must be triggered on the client PC.

Any ideas where to start?

Comment: you want to use the [TcpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx) class Here is [an article](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server) which examples its usage.

Comment: `Have googled, and stumbled across old sites with useless info` ? What do you think has changed?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're working in .NET, look at TcpClient and TcpListener.

Here's the MSDN documentation on TcpListener:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 5):

Start from the [TcpListener Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) MSDN topic.  It contains even the example which should be helpful to you.

Comment: OP already mentioned `TcpListener` in his tags.